# string concatenation convert to int and perform calculation

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have the following

```
 string = "make {0}{1} in {2} to produce {0}{1} in {2} minutes";
```

This pulls the correct values for `{0}` `{1}` `{2}` which works fine, for the second `{0}` `{1}` I want to divide the value for `{0}` by 2.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help

Comment: Use string interpolation instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a format string and not a calculation string.

So you'll have to do the calculation yourself, causing the positional arguments to increment in number (3 in this case):

```
string = string.Format("make {0}{1} in {2} to produce {3}{1} in {2} minutes", 
                       val0, val1, val2, val0 / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
string = $"make {var1}{var2} in {var3} to produce {var1/2}{var2} in {var3} minutes";
```

If that does not work due to language version restrictions, it can be done through `string.Format()` like this:

```
string = string.Format("make {0}{1} in {2} to produce {3}{1} in {2} minutes", var1, var2, var3, var1/2);
```

Comment: And what if the OP is using C# 5.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Microsoft suggest to use "$" character to interpolate strings. This make code more readable and concise. A basic usage is like this :

```
 double speedOfLight = 299792.458;
 string message = $"The speed of light is {speedOfLight} km/s.";
```

In your case it should be :

```
string result = $"make {0/2}{1} in {2} to produce {0/2}{1} in {2} minutes";
```

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolation expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a result string, items with interpolation expressions are replaced by the string representations of the expression results. This feature is available starting with C# 6.
>
> String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to
>   create formatted strings than a [`string composite formatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) feature.